# Macport self update fail mountain lion. Earlier it was working fine

Tags: macports

Macport self update fail mountain lion. Earlier it was working fine.

```
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

its seems like timeout but internet connection is working well.

Comment: How long since you have this problem?

Comment: i don't know but it was working well before 2 weeks. Today i tried to update and its showing me this error.

Comment: I just did a selfupdate myself, no troubles here (10.8.4 system). Have you tried `telnet rsync.macports.org 873`? You should see an rsync prompt that looks something like this `@RSYNCD: 30.0`. Anyway, if your problem persists you should probably ask this question again on superuser.com, because StackOverflow is programming oriented.

Comment: @herzbube I posted the same question on superuser but didn't get any answer. `telnet rsync.macports.org 873` give me following error:
    `Trying 17.251.224.58...
    telnet: connect to address 17.251.224.58: Operation timed out
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host` 
its seems like connection error but internet is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://distfiles.macports.org/ports.tar.gz
cp  ports.tar.gz /opt/local/var/macports/sources/distfiles.macports.org/
```

delete old ports document，upzip ports.tar.gz